# How to reset a kid's forgotten phone lock-screen password?

Tags: lock-screens

My 6-year-old grandson has now made two (ancient) phones useless by changing his password, and then forgetting it. He only uses phones in my house every few weeks.

On my Windows 10 LAPTOP, he has a "Standard" account. I'm the Administrator. Using that configuration, If he forgets his password, I simply reset it and then tell him the value.

Is it possible to do the same thing on an Android phone?

I think there are apps to prevent him downloading stuff, but I haven't found any app that would allow an Administrator to reset a forgotten password.

Thanks.

Comment: Download Android multi tools and you can reset by pressing 2 on your keyboard

Comment: I was researching the multi-tools a few days ago. Something made me suspicious. I did some Googling. Results were 50-50. I would prefer 100-0. Thanks.

Comment: So the grandson isn't on [Google Family Link](https://families.google.com/familylink/) with the parents? If the loaner devices are older than Android 4.4, then can you set him up as a secondary account so that at worse, you'll have to delete his profile and not factory reset a device.

Comment: @Morr. No GFM with parents. Phone is only used in my house. I researched "secondary account". That would be my fallback if there's nothing more sophisticated.

Comment: you can use google account password as fallback when device is completely locked after 10 wrong pin/pattern attempts

Answer (score 0):

Download find my device and make it device administrator(which is enabled by default i think..).. And if the kid changes password then you can reset it from the find my device website using your laptop.. Just ensure that the phone has internet connection while trying to reset it..

[WEBSITE](https://www.google.com/android/find)

[APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm&hl=en_IN)

DON'T FORGET TO DO A TEST RUN..

If anything goes wrong just comment here.. I'll help